# Check if a place is available by date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am a junior developer and I am trying to create an application to reserve a seat in an open-space on Spring boot with postgresql.

I want to be able to check if the place is not already booked during the duration desired by the user. I already did the database but I'm blocking on how to proceed with the verification.

example : i have already an event :

```
{
    id:'1',
    name :'Pepito',
    start:'2019-01-01 00:01:00',
    end:'2019-03-06 00:01:00',
    desk_id:'16'
}
```

start and end columns are timestamp without time zone type.

I want to insert a new event without it happening at the same time as other events having the same desk_id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a workplace is free by date, you need to run the following query:

```
select case when count(*) > 0 then false else true end as available from my_table WHERE desk_id = $YOUR_DESK_ID and not (
  (start < '$YOUR_START_DATE' and end < '$YOUR_START_DATE') 
   or
  (start > '$YOUR_END_DATE' and end > '$YOUR_END_DATE') 
);
```

The query result will return true or false. This way you can check before adding a new record.